# How to link mysqlcppconn.lib to a c++ project

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio

I'm trying to use the mysqlcppconn.lib in my c++ project. However, when I put use functionality from the library I get an error:

```
 Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _mysql_init@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Achievement::set(void)" (?set@Achievement@@QAEXXZ) zombie  C:\Users\jorda\OneDrive - Limerick Institute Of Technology\College\Final Year Project\Achievement_Libary\Copy - Copy\zombie\Achievement.obj 1
```

The code I'm using:

```
    MYSQL* conn;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL_RES* res;
    conn = mysql_init(0);
```

The errors seems to come from the mysql_init(0);

I've tried both the 32 and 64-bit version of the library but both give the same error. I'm not sure if I need to put some dlls inside the executable directory. I've tried putting libssl-1_1.dll & libcrypto-1_1.dll from both the 32 bit and 64-bit files as that's what one tutorial did however this did not work.

[image: asdasd]

[image]

Would anyone know the process of trying to use the C++ connector in a visual studio project? Any help is appreciated. Here are the lib and input paths from the Linker

Answer (score 0):

> > Would anyone know the process of trying to use the C++ connector in a visual studio project?

I suggest you could try the following steps:

1,Add the path to the header file to the Additional Include Directories(property - >c/c++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories)

2,Add the path to the .lib file to the Additional Library Directories (property -> linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories)

3,Add the name of the .lib file with its extension to Additional Dependencies (property -> linker -> input -> Additional Dependencies)

I suggest you could try to check if the file is in the location that you specified, or if you have provided the correct library path. And you couldn't mix 32 bit and 64 bit. Please make sure you're linking in 64-bit libraries with the 64-bit application, or change your app to 32-bit and link with the 32-bit libraries.

Comment: tried linking a 32 bit version and 64 of the c++ connector but it has the same error.

Comment: @Madmitten Whether you have correctly linked mysqlcppconn.lib according to the above three steps?