# How to use C++ connector for visual studio project

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, mysql-connector

I'm currently trying to connect my visual studio project to a database. I have successfully attached MySQL server lib to the project. I'm now trying to get mysqlcppconn.lib to work with the project. I added the mysqlcppconn.lib inside of the Linker input. I have tried both 32 and 64 bit version of the connector. However, I get an error at runtime. Would anyone know how to fix this. Really stuck at the moment and could use the help.

**C++ include and linked paths inside of the project:**

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\lib64\vs14
```

**File path to c++ connector files:**

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0
```

**Code I'm trying to get to work:**

```
MYSQL* conn;
MYSQL_ROW row;
MYSQL_RES* res;
conn = mysql_init(NULL);
```

The error that appears at runtime:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _mysql_init@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl smain(void)" (?smain@@YAXXZ)  zombie  C:\Users\jorda\OneDrive - Limerick Institute Of Technology\College\Final Year Project\Achievement_Libary\Copy - Copy\zombie\Source.obj  1
```

Comment: Related if not a duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66665802/how-to-link-mysqlcppconn-lib-to-a-c-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66665802/how-to-link-mysqlcppconn-lib-to-a-c-project)

Comment: ya checked that question. It didn't seem to have the answer to my problem

Comment: You will probably have to wait for this. Some questions take days to answer.

Comment: The error you get is not a runtime error. It is a linker error. Examples of an error at runtime would be an error code an exception or a popup in the debugger. All of these require that the build succeeded and you get an executable.